# Bubble Plot Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bubble-chart

I have the following code creating the graph below:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(15,17), sharex=True)

sns.scatterplot(data=merged, x="gdp_per_capita", y="life_expectancy", 
                size="death_rate", hue="continent", 
                cmap="Accent", sizes=(100, 1500), ax=ax1)
sns.scatterplot(data=merged, x="gdp_per_capita", y="human_development_index", 
                size="death_rate", hue="continent", 
                cmap="Accent", sizes=(100, 1500),  ax=ax2)

ax1.set(xlabel='GDP per Capita', ylabel ='Life Expectancy', title='Choose')
ax2.set(xlabel='GDP per Capita', ylabel ='Human Development Index', title='Choose')

# show the graph
plt.show()
```

[image: Bubble plot for GDP against Development indicators]

How can I separate the legend into two part, one for continent colour in upper right, the other for death rate bubble size in lower right? And so the bubbles fit within the legend?

PS: For testing purposes, here is a similar example using the "tips" dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips["percentage"] = tips["tip"] / tips["total_bill"] * 100
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time",
                size="percentage", sizes=(100, 1500))
```

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456956/separate-seaborn-legend-into-two-distinct-boxes).