# How to redraw seaborn legend entries while preserving markers?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to redraw a Seaborn legend with multiple factors (The default format is not very nice looking) by grouping the factor values into multiple legends (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457167/2052625)). However, when I do this, I lose the markers associated with line objects. Here is a toy example that doesn't actually break up the factor labels (just redraws everything together):

Plot with original legend:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Factor 1':['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
                   'Factor 2':['a','b','a','b','a','b'],
                   'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'y':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})


ax = sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y',
                  hue='Factor 1',
                  style='Factor 2',
                  markers=True, markersize=10)
```

[image]

Plot with redrawn legend:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y',
                  hue='Factor 1',
                  style='Factor 2',
                  markers=True, markersize=10)

lgd = ax.get_legend()
labels_all = [str(x._text) for x in lgd.texts]
handles_all = lgd.legendHandles

ax.legend(handles = handles_all,
          labels = labels_all)
```

[image: Markers missing from legend]

I'm not sure whether this is specific to Seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is just following [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457167/2052625) more faithfully. This works:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y',
                  hue='Factor 1',
                  style='Factor 2',
                  markers=True, markersize=10)

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles = h,
          labels = l)
```

[image]

It would be great if someone can explain why the way I originally tried didn't work!

Comment: This seems like a bug in matplotlib? `plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], "o-", label="line");
plt.legend().legendHandles[0].get_marker()` -> `"'` when it should be `"o"`.